# Process monitor Oracle Database connectivity check

Tags: .net, database, oracle11g, odac

I have windows 7(64bit).I am getting ORA:12154 could not resolve tns name issue.I did basic investigation nothing came up.using process monitor how to see where the application is picking up the TNSNAMES.ORA file.what else should i check using process monitor for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured that out.TNSNAMES.ORA file was in the incorrect folder